# How to handle ToggleButton state in OnPause and OnResume state

Tags: android, onresume, onpause, android-togglebutton, activity-state

I am facing problem with toggle button state on `onResume()` and `onPause()` state.

Activity - A (first user toggle ON the button) then go back to Activity - B, then it will comeback to Activity - A then I want toggle Button is ON not OFF, how to handle this state in android.

Comment: Have you call `override` `onResume` and `onPause` in your `Activity`? if so, have call `super.onResume()` and `super.onPause()`?

Comment: yes i am implemented these methods

Comment: Do you want the same toggleButton state after closing and reopening the app? If so try using Shared Preferences

Comment: ill integrated the shared preference it working fine for now @MangaldeepPannu

Answer (score 1):

By default `Activity` handles its components state which has an `id` attribute.

If it's not acting like that, you can use `onSaveInstanceState` and `onRestoreInstanceState` to handle components state manually:

```
@Override
public void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
  super.onSaveInstanceState(savedInstanceState);

  savedInstanceState.putBoolean("Toggle1", toggle.isChecked());
  // etc.
}
```

And to restore the state:

```
@Override
public void onRestoreInstanceState(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
  super.onRestoreInstanceState(savedInstanceState);

  boolean toggle1State = savedInstanceState.getBoolean("Toggle1");
  toggle1.setCheched(toggle1State);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 toggle_relative.setOnToggleChanged(new ToggleButton.OnToggleChanged() {
        @Override
        public void onToggle(boolean on) {
            if (on == true){
                SharedPreferences.Editor editor = preferences.edit();
                editor.putBoolean("toggle_relative", true); // value to store
                editor.commit();
                Toast.makeText(getContext(),"Relatives will be notified in case of accidental situation",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }else {
                SharedPreferences.Editor editor = preferences.edit();
                editor.putBoolean("toggle_relative", false); // value to store
                editor.commit();
            }
        }
    });







  @Override
public void onResume() {
    super.onResume();

    boolean boll_toggle_relative = preferences.getBoolean("toggle_relative", false);  //default is true
    if (boll_toggle_relative == true)
    {
        toggle_relative.setToggleOn();
    }
    else
    {
        toggle_relative.setToggleOff();
    }

}
```

Comment: `SharedPreferences` is not appropriate in this case, it will cause unexpected behavior if you lunch more than one instance of your `Activity`

Comment: But it working fine for now, if it create any issue then ill change the code, @Mosius